# Font awesome not embedded to PDF when exporting from Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts

I created a word document and used a custom font which is `FontAwesome`. I added the font using the default way of adding the font for Windows System. Adding the `ttf` of `FontAwesome`.

When I'm trying to export the file as a `PDF`,  the font was not embedded. And most of the icons is missing, and some of it is showing.

This is the **Word** file

[image]

---

This is the exported **PDF** from Word

[image]

So as you can see, some of the icons is visible, and some of it was not. I added the `Regular`, `Solid`, and `Brands` of `FontAwesome`.

What am I missing in here? Thanks.

Things i tried.
I already tried to amend the settings of Microsoft Office like in [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/106681/how-to-embed-fonts-in-a-microsoft-word-document/), but still no luck.

Comment: When exporting the PDF, did you in the Save As dialog click on Options and check the box for "ISO 19005-1 compliant (PDF/A)" ?

Comment: @harrymc yep, I tried to check that PDF/A. But still the problem occur

Comment: In *File > Options > Save*,  under "Preserve fidelity when sharing this document", did you check "Embed fonts in the file"?

Comment: @harrymc yes, I already tried that too.

Comment: Seems like you did everything correctly, so the problem is with Word. I suggest to install Adobe Acrobat Reader, which may install a ribbon pane in Word. Use Acrobat Reader to create the PDF, but check first that all font embedding options are set.

Comment: MS Word will not embed fonts if the font has an internal non-embed flag set. I suspect this is the case for your FontAwesome file.

Comment: So apparently, all those icons that was not rendered to the MS Word has an issue like this. Cos when I tried to install the font to Mac and generate a PDF, it was generated successfully without this error. I think this issue cause from FontAwesome itself or the way Windows 10 render the icon of Font Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

At least for me, this seems to be an issue with the current versions of Fontawesome. I had the same issues like you, but managed to get it working with [version 5.6.3-desktop](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases/tag/5.6.3).

There also appears to be a [open issue in Fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/14614) that pointed me in the right direction. However, make sure **not** to check "ISO 19005-1 compliant (PDF/A)" as this gave only white boxes for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with FontAwesome version 5.13.0, icons were perfectly visible in MS Word but translated into white boxes when exported to PDF. What worked for me: changing the MS Word settings to embed font (Mac Users: Word -> Preferences -> Save -> Check 'Embed fonts in file') along with checking 'Best for printing' while saving to a PDF.

Comment: Checking `Best for printing` will detach the links that you embed to the text as a hyperlink. This might be a workaround, but not a fix